# Godot with C# command line problem EditorSettings::_get - Property not found

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot

When I open Godot and try to create new project this prompt with this error pops up:

```
Mono: Logfile is: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming/Godot/mono/mono_logs/2020_05_19 23.56.43 (2276).txt
WARNING: _get: EditorSettings::_get - Property not found: mono/editor/editor_path_optional
     At: editor/editor_settings.cpp:151
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [harmless but known issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/36995) which will be [fixed in Godot 3.2.2](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/37210).